# Status pin of a charger IC

Tags: power-electronics, charger

I am using the LT3652 charger chip,[datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3652fe.pdf). Now, there is a status pin /CHRG. The pin is -

**CHRG (Pin 4): Open-Collector Charger Status Output;
typically pulled up through a resistor to a reference voltage.
This status pin can be pulled up to voltages as high
as VIN when disabled, and can sink currents up to 10mA
when enabled. During a battery charging cycle, if required
charge current is greater than 1/10 of the programmed
maximum current (C/10), CHRG is pulled low. A temperature
fault also causes this pin to be pulled low. After
C/10 charge termination or, if the internal timer is used
for termination and charge current is less than C/10, the
CHRG pin remains high-impedance.**

Now, an application circuit is as shown below -

[image: application circuit]

Now, it says that the /CHRG pin can sink in a max of 10mAmps and it shows an LED connected to show status. Most SMD LEDs need approx 10mAmps at least to make it turn on. I cannot supply 10mAmps as thats the maximum. So, what practical use could it serve ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Most SMD LEDs need approx 10mAmps at least to make it turn on*

From where did you get this wisdom ? Most LEDs already start to glow a bit at 1 mA. It is not that they **need** 10 mA to do anything.

*I cannot supply 10mAmps as thats the maximum*

Uhm, that means that it **can** sink up to 10 mA which is enough for most LEDs. Only if you would be using **very old and inefficient** LEDs would 10 mA not be enough. I'm talking LEDs that are 20 years old !

If you insist on more current for your LEDs, use the charging IC's output to toggle a PNP transistor and let the transistor supply the current to the LED. Instead of a PNP you could also use a PMOS.